# HTML - reduce byte size

Tags: html, css

I'm testing a website speed using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)  tool.

In the result page, one of the warnings suggested me to reduce byte size of **css**, **html** and **js** files.
At the first I tried to remove comments, but nothing changed.
How can I do that?
Should I remove spaces and tabs?
It seems to be a very long operation, worth it?

Comment: You can have a look at minified CSS and JS - there are online tools to help you.

Comment: you can google for css/js optimizer.. lots of optimizers available.. after optimizing just check the page is working properly or not again.. becoz sometimes it omits gradients colors etc..

Answer (score 8):

The action of removing spaces, tabs and useless chars is called **minify**.
You don't need to do that, there are a lot of services that can minimize files for you.
for example:
http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Be care if you have jquery code: sometimes it removes spaces in wrong place.

Comment: Not just if one has jQuery. Vanilla/native Javascripts with `//comments` rather than `/*comments*/` often get broken, too.

Comment: Right, it happened to me too

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to do to reduce page size:

- Minify CSS & JS files

In server side, if you are running your website via Apache, you can install APC, for page cahing. You'll have better parformances

- APC

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, after further testing and incorporating the issues discussed in the comments below:

**PageSpeed Insights is an utterly amateurish tool, and there are much more effective ways to speed up the rendering time than minifying the codes.**

[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) is an utterly amateurish tool, that *as a matter of standard* advises to reduce HTML, CSS and JS file sizes, if not minified. A much, much better tool is [Pingdom Website Speed Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/). That compares rendering speed to the average of the sites it is asked to test, and gives the download times of the site's components.

Just test www.gezondezorg.org on both, and see the enormous difference in test results. At which the Google tool is dead wrong. It advises to reduce the CSS and JS files, while its own figures (click the respective headers) show that doing so will reduce their sizes with 3.8 and 7.9 kB, respectively. That comes down to less than 1 millisecond download time difference! (1 millisecond = 1/1000 of a second; presumed broadband internet).

Also, it says that I did do a good thing: enable caching. That is BS as well, because my .htaccess file tells browsers to check for newly updated files at every visit, and refresh cached files whenever updated. Tests confirm that all browsers heed that command.

Furthermore, that site is not intended to be viewed on mobile phones. There is just way too much text on it for that. Nevertheless, PageSpeed Insights opens default with the results of testing against mobile-phone criteria.

**More effective ways to speed up the rendering**
So, minifying hardly does anything to speed up the rendering time. What does do that is the following:

- Put your CSS codes and Javascripts as much as possible in one file each. That saves browser-to-server (BTS) requests. (Do keep in mind that quite a number of Javascripts need the DOM to be fully loaded first, so in practice it comes down to putting the scripts as much as possible in 2 files: a pre- and a post-body file.)
- Optimize large images for the web. Photoshop and the likes even have a special function for that, reducing the file size while keeping the quality good enough for use on the web.
- In case of images that serve as full-size background for containers: use image sprites. That saves BTS requests as well.
- Code the HTML and JS files so that there is no rendering dependency on files from external domains, such as from Twitter, Facebook, Google Analytics, advertisement agencies, etc.
- Make sure to get a web-host that will respond swiftly, has a sufficient processing capacity, and has a(n almost) 100% up-time.
- Use vanilla/native JS as much as possible. Use jQuery or other libraries only for tasks that would otherwise be too difficult or too time-consuming. jQuery not only is an extra file to download, it is also processed slower than native JS.

Lastly, you should realize that:

- having the server minify the codes on the fly generally results in a much slower response from the server;
- minifying a code makes it unreadable;
- de-minifying tools are notorious for their poor performance.

Comment: its always a good practice to minify css, js & HTML for production however you will obviously keep un-minified version to work on for dev.

Comment: @AamirShahzad - The tests and statistics prove you wrong. Take this SO page (with AdBlocker enabled): normal size: 82 kB, minified: 62 kB. That's only 20 kB difference, while the average US household download speed is 25 *m*B/s - see http://www.netindex.com/download/2,1/United-States/. That's roughly 25.000 kB/s! 20 kB size difference gives a download time difference of no more than 1 millisecond (0.0008 seconds). No client will want to pay extra for such a totally negligible difference.

Comment: if your target market is with avg bandwidth of 25+ Mbs then minify or un-minified doesn't matters but still doing it is advantage, but bigger clients who aren't focusing just one country do consider every  extra byte, people are using old dial in lots of country i have my self left it 2years ago... here is an excellent read. http://blog.kissmetrics.com/speed-is-a-killer/ other than this it effects seo. read this too http://moz.com/blog/how-website-speed-actually-impacts-search-ranking, good luck!

Comment: @AamirShahzad - A size difference of 20 kB for an HTML web page is negligible also if the user is on dial-up. You would better have advised the OP to optimize his site by means of image optimization for the web, using image sprites, putting CSS and JS as much as possible in one file each, and getting rendering-independent of files from other domains. Those, plus using native JS rather than jQuery, are the variables that make websites notably faster. Not minifying text file sizes. That does drive up the cost of a website, but does as good as nothing for the rendering speed.

Comment: I'm with Frank on this one.  There is a real tendency for SEOs to implement changes without considering the impact on other aspects of a site.  Minifying code has quite a few negative implications, particularly for someone else taking over the code and making any changes to the code.  I worry SEOs will see tools like Google's PageSpeed test as a checklist that must be done rather than things to consider the pros and cons of.  If code is minimised, make sure the un-minimised file is always uploaded alongside it.

Comment: @FrankConijn i used to work on products which has around 20+ js files around 2mb+ css files (not minified) and tons of HTML... here 20kb from each does matters...

Comment: @RichardB No SEO, No fast page load, i should not do is bcz of one reason that new user who will work will have to unmnify code... this is not a valid reason. see my first comment. I recommended it for production not dev.

Comment: @AamirShahzad - You used to work on sites with around 20+ JS files, around 2mb+ CSS files, and tons of HTML, while only 2 years ago you still had dial-up internet?

Comment: @AamirShahzad - My comment goes to the credibility of the factual statements you made. Which helps the reader to determine who to believe.

Comment: @AamirShahzad You linked to articles on moz.com which are entirely about SEO.  You have not actually said *why* you recommend it for production, or why a second dev having to unminify it is not a valid reason not to do it.   As I say, leaving an unminified copy on the server would solve that particular problem, but you suggest just leaving it on your dev server.  Any dev taking over would get unreadable, undocumented code.  There may be good reasons do do it - eg if your client base is using dial-up, then it makes sense.   However, it is about balancing the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CSS minifier/prettifier tools above, I recommend using [proCSSor](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/) for optimizing CSS files. It offers variety of advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

Never found those tools to be much use beyond giving some tips for what *might* be slowing it down.  Minifying is unlikely to achieve much.  If you want to speed up your site, save the page and see what the largest files are.  Generally they will be the image files rather than the code, and see if you can reduce these.

Also, try and test it on two servers - is your host slow?

If your html file is massive, that suggests a problem with the site's structure - it is rare that a page needs to be large.

Finally, large javascript files are most likely to be things like jquery.  If Google hosts these, then use the hosted version.  That way, it will probably be already in a user's cache and not impact on your loading time.

Answer (score -2):

Minifying resources refers to eliminating unnecessary bytes, such as extra spaces, line breaks, and indentation. Compacting HTML, CSS, and JavaScript can speed up downloading, parsing, and execution time. In addition, for CSS and JavaScript, it is possible to further reduce the file size by renaming variable names as long as the HTML is updated appropriately to ensure the selectors continue working.

You can find plenty of online tools for this purpose, a few of them are below.

[HTML Minify](http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/)
[CSS Minify](http://cssminifier.com/)
[JS Minify](http://jscompress.com/)

good luck!